# PHP current not accessing first (and only) array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this data structure below, which is a print_r of $_GET:

```
 Array (
     [url] => search/
     [q] => shirt
     [view_all] => 
     [price_float_GBP] => Array
         (
             [0] => 107
         )
 )
```

Why does `$_GET['price_float_GBP'][0]` work but `current($_GET['price_float_GBP'])` doesn't?

Sorry if this is a newbie question but I don't quite see it.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? (Works as expected for 5.3.)

Comment: I don't know why that array's internal pointer would have been moved, but does `reset()` also fail?

Comment: Also works for me in PHP 5.2. This doesn't seem like it would be a version-related bug issue.

Comment: Hmmm...I posted a reply to @mario but it was deleted for some reason? I am using PHP 5.1.6.

Comment: @Wiseguy: There have been numerous changes with zval stuff after 5.1, and $_GET in particular is build by early init code. But just build a 5.1.0 CGI and I can't reproduce this behaviour. So it might be some code before that. Even though I'm confused how you could set the internal array pointer out of bounds. @crmpicco: Don't you get any error message or notice? Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` beforehand.

Comment: @crmpicco: 1. Accept more answers. 2. Try localizing the $_GET array to a local array and try `current` on the local version. `$myArray = $_GET; current($myArray['price_float_GBP']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual it's possible the pointer to be beyond the end of the elements list. This can easily happen if you use foreach on that array.

Cheers.